# LimitRequestFieldSize does not work in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am using Apache 2.4 and trying to increase the Request header size to more than the default. I modified the httpd.conf and added

`LimitRequestFieldSize 12136` 
to increase as per [Apache Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html)

Tried adding in the server config as well as inside the Virtual Host. Neither of them works.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: did you restart?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue by adding `LimitRequestFieldSize 32768` and `LimitRequestLine 32768` in the httpd.conf file. This setting I have put above all the include file Directive in httpd.conf.